# Mapping two tables

Tags: database, hibernate, relational-database, one-to-many

Now then, I have two tables named Devices and Systems. 
Devices-- contains information about all mouses, cpu, keyboards, monitors,projectors, etc. Basically everything that is present in an IT company office. Attributes are (device_id[primary key],in_office_since,assigned_to)

Systems-- Now this is basically a collection of devices. For Example a mouse, a cpu, a monitor together form a single system.

A System can any number of devices in it. For Example it could only consist of a cpu and a projector.
Attributes of a system are (system_id[auto generated by hibernate using @GeneratedValue],device_id_1,device_id_2,...) where device_id_1 and similarly named columns are foreign keys referring device_is in Devices table or relation.

There is a one to many relation from system to devices.

Now I am not able to figure out, how to make the above mapping where one of the tables has variable number of attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should design it as a normal one-to-many relation. So,

your **`devices`** table would have:

- `device_id` (PK)
- `in_office_since`
- `assigned_to`
- `system_id` (FK that references `systems` table, can be NULL if a given device is not part of any system)

and your **`systems`** table:

- `system_id` (PK)
- ...

That way, you can have systems that are comprised of any number of devices. This is the canonical way to set up a one-to-many relation, and it will be trivial to map with Hibernate.